# How to create a RAM disk from the Kickstart environment?

Tags: centos, kickstart, mkfs, ramdisk

I'm installing a CentOS 7 VM, and I would like to create a RAM disk inside the `%pre` section of a Kickstart file.

However, doing so via

```
mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
```

is not possible as the `mkfs` binary is not present in the Kickstart environment, and all other `mkfs.*` filesystem-specific commands return an error "/dev/ram1: no such file or directory".

Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the device node needed to be created with

```
mknod /dev/ram1 b 1 1
```

Once this is done, it can be formatted via e.g. `mkfs.ext2`:

```
mkfs.ext2 /dev/ram1 8192
```